# Generate all permutations of a list in lexicagraphical order

Tags: python, list, while-loop, permutation

I am very much a beginner. I am trying to write a program that, given the number of elements (1-9) in the list as a parameter, will then output all permutations of the list in lexicographical order. In the program it is adding on each permutation as a list into a larger list that contains all the permutations in order. Although the program is not working as expected in general, one main problem I'm having is with this while loop In line 10, I want the list to stop compiling once the final permutation has been added to the list. For example, if my input parameter is n = 4, the last permutation/element should be [4,3,2,1]. However, when I run this program, that element is in the list three times at the end. I don't know how this is so when it should terminate that while loop once it has been added.

```
def ourPermutations(n):
    x=list(range(1,n+1))
    permList = []
    permList+=[x]

    xcopy = x[:]
    finalPerm = xcopy[::-1]


    while x != finalPerm:
        istar = n-2
        while x[istar] > x[istar+1]:
            istar -= 1
        jstar = n-1
        while x[jstar] < x[istar]:
            jstar -= 1
        x[istar],x[jstar] = x[jstar],x[istar]
        if istar+1 == n-1:
            x = x[:]
        else:
            a = x[istar+1:]
            a = a[::-1]
            x = x[:istar+1] + a
        permList += [x]

    return permList
```

That is my main question; however, this program is still missing elements when I run it. It isn't quite working, so if you see a spot where something is obviously wrong, feel free to tell me that particular line is what is causing my problems. If it helps, this is based on this identical (and correct) version written in Mathematica 8:

```
ourpermutations[n_] := (
    ourlist = {x=Range[1,n]};
    While[
        x != Reverse[Range[1,n]],
        istar = n-1;
        While[x[[istar]] > x[[istar+1, istar--];
        jstar = n; While[x[[jstar]] < x[[istar]], jstar--];
        x[[{istar, jstar}]] = x[[{jstar, istar}]];
        AppendTo[ourlist, x = Join[Take[x,istar], Reverse[Drop[x,istar]]]]
    ];
    ourlist
)
```

So this is what my Python code should be doing; I just can't get it to do so just yet. Thanks for any of your time and effort.

Comment: Not an answer, but, `itertools.permutations()` might be helpful in case you don't care about the implementation.

Comment: What is the output of `ourPermutations(3)` supposed to look like?

Comment: Thanks, but a professor just asked us to try and see if we could get this to work in other languages. The output should look like this:

    [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're running into a problem because you aren't copying `x` soon enough and so you're sometimes modifying `x` after it's been added to `permList`.  This can be solved by adding `x = x[:]` at the start of your while loop:

```
def ourPermutations(n):
    x=list(range(1,n+1))
    permList = []
    permList+=[x]

    xcopy = x[:]
    finalPerm = xcopy[::-1]

    while x != finalPerm:
        x = x[:]
        istar = n-2
        while x[istar] > x[istar+1]:
            istar -= 1
        jstar = n-1
        while x[jstar] < x[istar]:
            jstar -= 1
        x[istar],x[jstar] = x[jstar],x[istar]
        if istar+1 == n-1:
            x = x[:]
        else:
            a = x[istar+1:]
            a = a[::-1]
            x = x[:istar+1] + a
        permList += [x]

    return permList

>>> ourPermutations(3)
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
>>> ourPermutations(4)
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4, 3], [1, 3, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4, 2], [1, 4, 2, 3], [1, 4, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3, 4], [2, 1, 4, 3], [2, 3, 1, 4], [2, 3, 4, 1], [2, 4, 1, 3], [2, 4, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 4, 2], [3, 2, 1, 4], [3, 2, 4, 1], [3, 4, 1, 2], [3, 4, 2, 1], [
4, 1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 3, 2], [4, 2, 1, 3], [4, 2, 3, 1], [4, 3, 1, 2], [4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

A slightly more "pythonic" version might look like:

```
def our_permutations(n):
    x = list(range(1, n+1))
    perm_list = [x]
    final_perm = x[::-1]

    while x != final_perm:
        x = x[:]
        istar = n-2
        while x[istar] > x[istar+1]:
            istar -= 1
        jstar = n-1
        while x[jstar] < x[istar]:
            jstar -= 1
        x[istar],x[jstar] = x[jstar],x[istar]
        if istar+1 != n-1:
            a = x[istar+1:]
            a = a[::-1]
            x = x[:istar+1] + a
        perm_list += [x]

    return perm_list
```

Checking these functions against `itertools.permutation` shows that they produce the same answers, so it looks like your algorithm was correct except for that small mistake.

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly now. Thank you so much! I'm still a little confused though why just adding that one line changes it. Why would it be changing the x that is in the permList?

Comment: @pomzer No problem, glad to help!  The problem is that without the `x=x[:]` line, x is still a reference to the list added to `permList`.  It's the same reason that if you do something like `a = [1, 2]; b = a; b[0] = 3;` then both a and b will be `[3, 2]`.